# Where can I read about Veblen functions / klammersymbols beyond the large Veblen ordinal?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, ordinal-numbers

So, I'm not sure to what extent this is a thing.  John Baez mentions in [this blog post](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/large-countable-ordinals-part-3/) that common large countable ordinals beyond the large Veblen ordinal can also "be defined as fixed points".  He doesn't expand on that but I take it that means fixed points of a further Veblen-like / klammersymbol-like construction.

But, I haven't been able to find any good account of this.  Is this a known/standard thing?  I want to know just how far the Veblen construction can be pushed -- like, beyond the large Veblen ordinal, is there an "ultimate Veblen ordinal" somewhere; and might it be equal to an already-named / well-known one, such as Bachmann-Howard?  (I suppose a negative answer here would be if arbitrarily large computable ordinals could be obtained this way, making the "ultimate Veblen ordinal" just $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$.)

Now I can certainly think of ways of continuing beyond the large Veblen ordinal myself... but I don't really want to reinvent the wheel here when I expect others have likely already done it better.  So, is there a good account of this somewhere?

Thank you all!

Comment: If one takes Veblen-like construction as an informal concept, then it would be hard to justify some $\alpha<\omega_1^{\mathsf{CK}}$ to be the ultimate Veblen ordinal (the suprema of all ordinals obtained by Veblen-style constructions). The reason for this is that it wouldn't be clear why one shouldn't be allowed to make the next step of diagonalization and overcome this particular ordinal.

Comment: However, I think that it is possible to give Bachmann-Howard ordinal as a (non-least) upper bound for reasonable constructions of this kind. The motivation here is that it is reasonable to expect that this constructions should be formalizable in Kripke-Platek set theory with infinity $\mathsf{KP}\omega$ and the proof-theoretic ordinal of $\mathsf{KP}\omega$ is Bachmann-Howard ordinal.

Comment: I think a link to original paper (of howard I think?) was posted on fom (if I am re-calling correctly). I don't think it was that long ago (maybe around an year or bit more). I will try to find and post the link (in few days perhaps). Other than that, one could probably find a number of relevant topics by using a search or following the links in some of the topics under "Related".

Comment: Here is the link I was referring to in comment above: https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.04609

Comment: @FedorPakhomov: Yes, that is the obvious problem; but I thought maybe if at some point there were some component to the construction which there were truly no way to iterate more than finitely many times, then you could take the limit of those and then be unable to continue further, as you simply wouldn't have enough to find a fixed-point.  But I don't have a good idea if that would happen or not.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov Also like -- it has to give out somewhere on account of it certainly can't get you past $\omega_1^{CK}$!  But if it can't, then there must be some concrete way in which the construction fails at that point; and since the construction of taking derivatives of appropriate sorts doesn't seem obviously related to computability, this raises the possibility that maybe that failure happens somewhere earlier?

Comment: @HarryAltman I think that it is very unlikely that there is some concrete point of failure. But in my opinion the reasoning that either there is a concrete point of failure or we could reach unlimitely large ordinals isn't valid. This is because we are dealing with an informal notion here. Furthermore, it is rather unlikely that any particular formalization would be completely satisfactory (precisely because then it would lead to a concrete point of failure, which we would be able to diagonalize against).

Comment: @HarryAltman However, this doesn't mean that we couldn't give some upper bound. We just need to have some necessary but not sufficient conditions for some construction to count as Veblen-like. I think that formalizability in $\mathsf{KP}\omega$ probably should be a necessary condition (which gives B-H ordinal as an upper bound). Basically, in order to show this (in an informal sense) we need to demonstrate that all the types of constructions and manipulations with them that could be building blocks of a Veblen-like construction are formalizable in $\mathsf{KP}\omega$.

Comment: @HarryAltman Essentially here I am using the same kind of argument as M. Rathjen have used in his paper on limits of Martin-Löf type theory http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/EHPanthology.pdf , where he argued that the strengths of this kinds of theories are bounded by the strength of the theory $\mathsf{KPM}$.

Comment: OK I'm confused by the Howard paper. He constructs $\Gamma_0$ in section 3, calling it $\lambda$, but I don't really follow the rest. Why does section 4 involve uncountables (and even $\omega_2$?!)?  And the subscripts here are individual ordinals, rather than there being multiple subscripts?  I'm confused; I don't really understand how this fits with what I know.

Comment: Oh, I think I see -- if you think in terms of sets and intersections rather than functions and fixed points and limits, the suggestion I gave above about how it could possibly terminate makes no sense.  So I guess it has to go to &omega;_1^{CK}$ after all, after that many steps (using some notional setup where we've, like, linearized the sequence of steps)...

Answer (score 2):

Here is some relevant information by a grandmaster on the subject:
[http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~buchholz/articles/jaegerfestschr_buchholz3.pdf](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/%7Ebuchholz/articles/jaegerfestschr_buchholz3.pdf)

Comment: OK, taking a look at this I'm afraid I don't understand this. He explains how to construct $\Gamma_\alpha$ in the preliminaries, but I'm having trouble following it beyond that.  His $\phi$ only has *one* subscript, but (going by the equation before Lemma 1.6) it acts like multiple (i.e., acts like Klammersymbols) if you go into uncountables?  I don't really understand how to get beyond that though, especially if merely getting beyond (the equivalent of) a single subscript requires getting to $\Omega$! I'd hope for each step to be somehow expressible in terms of things constructed so far...